# Elasticsearch group by query does not return all the documents

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am using elastic `6.7.1` In my index there is a field `cid` and I am trying to group them with this field.

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_cid": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "cid",
        "order": {
          "_count": "desc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It shows 5 result with count more than 1 with other results having count 1, but I know there is another group of this cid with value 21 that has count 2 and not shown in the result.
Here is the response

```
{
  "took" : 101,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 530161,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "group_by_cid" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 5,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 530143,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "15929",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "29",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "4781",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "48387",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "547",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "0303141597270",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "0404091598267",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "0606021000357",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "0606021000359",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "0606021000364",
          "doc_count" : 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

So I added the following filter

```
        "min_doc_count": 2
```

Now it shows same 5 docs, still without 21.

Finally when I add this to the query

```
"query": {
    "term": {
      "cid": {
        "value": "21"
      }
    }
  },
```

It shows group with cid 21 and shows count 2. Here is the response

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "group_by_cid" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "21",
          "doc_count" : 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Why it is not shown in the first query? How do I get all the groups with count more than 2?

Comment: Can you also show the response you get?

Comment: @Val please check updated question, i have added responses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see that you have non-zero [`doc_count_error_upper_bound`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_per_bucket_document_count_error) and [`sum_other_doc_count`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#terms-agg-doc-count-error) which means that some of your buckets have been dropped (explained in details why in the links above)

What you can do to improve the situation is to specify a [bigger `shard_size`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-shard-size) to get more accurate results. By default, `shard_size = 1.5 * size + 10` and since `size` is 10 by default, it means `shard_size` is 25, which might be too low if some of your documents are now properly scattered among your shards and/or if some of your buckets are too big.

Try like this and increase `shard_size` until you get the desired results:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_cid": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "cid",
        "shard_size": 100,          <-----  add this
        "order": {
          "_count": "desc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Had to increase to 100000, seems to much

Comment: If most of your buckets have two documents and you're sorting by _count, then it means that you need to consider all documents (i.e. 5 shards * 100000 shard size), otherwise there's no deterministic way to get what you want, unless you add some query to restrict the number of documents to aggregate.